# Need to bypass Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: AS3 loading external video swf

Tags: actionscript-3, air2

It´s me again.. I need to go to frame 2 on a AIR2 app but the sandbox deal is driving me crazy...

This is how I load the MovieClikp:

```
function startLoad()
{
var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/Player-More/video/index.swf");
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
mLoader.load(mRequest);
}
function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
{
        addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
function onProgressHandler(mProgress:ProgressEvent)
{
var percent:Number = mProgress.bytesLoaded/mProgress.bytesTotal;
trace(percent);

}
startLoad();
```

And this is the actionscript I have in the last frame of the loaded movie:

```
MovieClip(parent.parent).play();
```

I never had this problems with AS2 and it's getting worse with every new update Adobe makes.

Sorry about that last comment, but I've tried every solution from other posts and I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're debugging locally you can add your local path where you're loading up the swf or html that loads the swf from in the flash player settings, right click and go to global settings then click global security settings panel in the links on the left, in the dialog pick your local filesystem location.
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

If you're accessing from one domain to another http://www.domain1.com/a.swf access http://www.domain2.com/b.swf then you have to have a http://www.domain2.com/crossdomain.xml that allows swf 1 to access swf 2.

Comment: The main Timeline is in a desktop AIR App and the loaded movie is in a remote server.
How do I call the XML from main timeline in my desktop app?

Comment: The cross domain file should be called automatically http://curtismorley.com/2007/09/01/flash-flex-tutorial-how-to-create-a-crossdomainxml-file/  Also the adobe docs http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html

Comment: You would just need to be sure it's served up from http://localhost/crossdomain.xml weird thing is I've never had problems with this when working with as3 but haven't used AS2 in a while.  It should occur with one site to another but an AIR app to localhost I wouldn't imagine would be a problem, did you try adding localhost as a trusted location as well?